# Howto upload files and limit acces to logged in users

Tags: cakephp, ckeditor

In a web application we use ckeditor to let the user generate content. We want to make it possible, that the user is able to upload files. We would like to upload this to a folder.

This folder should now only be accesible for logged in users. Is there a way to combine Cake's Auth-Component to control access to this folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to store the files in a folder not accessible from the browser outside of the webroot and send the files through php.

See [this section](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#sending-files) of the book that explains how to send files using the response object. You action will use whatever auth adapter you've configured. So only people who are allowed to access that action will receive the file.

I've written [a plugin that deals with files and storage systems](https://github.com/burzum/FileStorage). Take a look at it if you like. It's managing the file references in the different storage adapters (local FS, S3, dropbox, memory...). It can also resize images. It features event so that you can modify files as needed before and after they're stored.

Comment: When the upload capabilities of ckeditor is used a link to the desired file is created automatically. We want to avoid that the user has to edit html-code. Would your suggestion be to rewrite a users request using cake's routes or Apache's rewrite facilities to route the request to the proper controller? Is my approach correct?

Comment: No, read the link to the CakePHP book. This is *not* routing. You actually send the data through php, php reads the data from a folder NOT accessible from the web and sends it to the browser. When you're using the ckeditors upload script I can't help you, this is not CakePHP then and I don't know the upload script from the editor.